# Selection surrounding in Vim

Tags: vim, terminal, macvim

What's the best way to surround a selected text in vim ?

e.g.

```
cout << this is some statement << endl;
```

and I want to quick surround this statement with " " to be

```
cout << "this is some statement" << endl;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) for all your surrounding needs.

Once installed, if your cursor is on the "t" of "this", type `yst<"` to accomplish what you want:

`ys<text object><type>` surrounds the text object with things of the type.

Comment: I'd like to add one little more trick in case someone else searching .. if we have some text like `cout << yes a < b << endl; ` in this case we can type `ys2t<"` to surround until the second "<" at the end of the text instead of the first "<" inside the text we want to surround itself.

Answer (score 7):

I love and use [Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) but doing it with vanilla Vim is dead simple:

```
c"<C-r>""<Esc>
```

which means "change the selected text (`c`) to a double quote (`"`), then insert the content of the unnamed register (`<C-r>"`), followed by another double quote (`"`), and leave insert mode (`<Esc>`)".

See `:help i_ctrl-r`.